# Getting instagram access token for Instagram gem requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, instagram

I'm trying to allow a user to select photos from their instagram feed in my application.

I'm using omniauth to authenticate the user thru the omniauth-instagram gem. I also have the official instagram rails gem, and when I run Instagram.user_recent_media(user_instagram_id), it tells me I need an access token.

I try saving the code parameter on the callback, but I cannot create an access token from this key. Any tips on pulling a user's media feed?

Answer (score 0):

I have had success doing the following:

```
client = Instagram.client(:access_token => token)
client.user_recent_media(:count => 200)
```

Comment: My problem is turning the code I get from the callback into an access token -- I always get a 400 error back

Comment: Are you getting a 400 from the redirect back to your app after successfully logging into instagram or is it happening at some other point?

Comment: it only happens when I request the access_token from the parameter code. I'm able to auth with Instagram just fine for logins

Comment: The token should be provided when processing the callback in the omniauth.auth hash: request.env['omniauth.auth']['credentials']['token']